# Behaviour of the function satisfying $f(x)+f(\frac{x-1}{x})=x+1$

Tags: functions, roots

> Question: Let $f:\mathbb R-\{0,1\}\to \mathbb R$ be a function satisfying $f(x)+f(\frac{x-1}{x})=x+1$, then both $f$ and $f'$ are not injective. (True or False)

I tried forming patterns and deduced that $f(x)=\frac{x^3-x^2-1}{2x(x-1)},x\ne0,1.$ To comment on whether $f,f'$ are injective, we have that $f'(x)=\frac{x^4-2x^3+x^2+2x-1}{2(x-1)^2x^2}$, need not be strictly increasing unless $x^4-2x^3+x^2+2x-1\geq0,x\in\mathbb R-\{0,1\}$.

Let $h(x)=x^4-2x^3+x^2+2x-1$, using Descartes' rule of sign $h(x)$ can have atmost $3$ positive real roots and $1$ negative real root. Observe that $h(0)=-1,h(1)=1$ although they are not in the domain but they will help determine in the roots, so this particular $h(x)$ must have atleast $1$ root in $(0,1)$.

Also $h'(x)=4x^3-6x^2+2x+2$ such that $h'(0)=2,h'(1)=2$ here the condition of Rolle's Theorem is applicable on $(0,1)$ as the assumed $h(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ then $\exists c\in(0,1)$ such that $h''(c)=0\implies12c^2-12c+2=0$. This will give the existence of $2$ real $c\in(0,1)$. **I lost my track after this, since if $f$ vanishes twice in the domain $\implies$ $f'$ vanishes atleast once, but $f'$ will not make us comment anything on the behaviour of $f$ as the converse of Rolle's need not help. Any hint would be appreciated**

The thing that created the doubt is as: $h'(x)$ is a cubic polynomial so it need not guarantee the existence of $3$ real roots, I used $h''$ to comment on the same and $h'$ has no root in $(0,1)$ but it is not one-one there as ell. I request not to use the graphing calculators to depict the behaviour of this function. I am looking for a simpler way to do this question .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ gets large and positive, without bound, both when $x$ is just above $0$, and also when $x$ is just below $1$.  So if $n$ is large enough, then the line $y=n$ will cut the graph of $f(x)$ both near $0$ and $1$.
$f^\prime(x)$ runs from very large and negative numbers near $x=0$ to very large and positive numbers near $x=1$.  So every line $y=n$ cuts the graph of $f^\prime(x)$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$.  Pick any $z\gt 1$.  Then the constant line $y=f^\prime(z)$ cuts the graph of $f^\prime(x)$ both at $x=z$ and for some $x\in(0,1)$